# Expressjs middleware example

Tags: node.js, express

Hellow I have code in my **app.js**, looking like that:

```
app.use('/someurl', require('./middleware/somemodule'));
```

-app.use instead app.all

and module looks like:

```
 if(process.env.BLALAL === undefined){ 
   throw "Error: process.env.BLALAL === undefined";
 }

 module.exports = function(req, res, next){
   ...
 }
```

is it a **bad** practice ?

Comment: What exactly do you think might be a bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

### As said on [the express api reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use):

[**`app.VERB(path, [callback...], callback)`**](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB)

> The `app.VERB()` methods provide the routing functionality in Express,
>   where VERB is one of the HTTP verbs, such as `app.post()`.

[**`app.use([path], function)`**](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use)

> Use the given middleware function, with optional mount path,
>   defaulting to "/".
>
> The "mount" path is stripped and is not visible to the middleware
>   function. The main effect of this feature is that mounted middleware
>   may operate without code changes regardless of its "prefix" pathname.

## IMO

The functionality may be nearly the same, but there is an underlying semantic meaning. The routes itself should be set through the `app.VERB` api, while any middleware should be set through the `app.use` api.

Normally *middlewares* **modify the `request` or `response` objects**, or **inject functionality from other module** that may answer the `request`, or not.

[`connect.static`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-static.html) is a good example. It could be really an [`app`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#express) or an [`HttpServer`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server) by itself, but is injected as middleware on other app object.

Comment: That was an superb answer.

Comment: @gustavohenke Do you think the definition I did is correct? I wrote it on the fly and surely it is concise and clear but I was wondering if it covers all the use cases.

Comment: Yes, I really think you did answered it well; I've been studying Node (not really working with it) has almostly a year, and thru this time my definition of middleware hits exactly what you answered.

Answer (score -1):

I personally don't like `require` inside other commands then `var bla = require('bla');`, it makes code much worse readable in my opinion and you did not get anything in return.

I am not sure what was your intention, but if your code depends on environment variable, it is better to throw immediately than later when your route is called. So `app.use` is better then `app.all`. But I don't understand why aren't you simply test your condition inside app.js and why you hide it in `somemodule`.

Comment: The exception *is* throw immediately, the `require` isn't delayed until a request comes is.

Comment: **>why aren't you simply test your condition inside app.js**


- because I want independent middleware module here (and use it in other apps)

Comment: This makes sense, but I still don't like your solution. I don't think that middleware should require environment variable. I would use parameter instead of environment variable. It is on application to decide where configuration is, in environment variables, hardcoded in app or somewhere in config.json.